# How to magnify a screen area in Lubuntu 18.04

Tags: lubuntu

There is a feature to magnify a screen area in Ubuntu. I've been trying it on Lubuntu 18 but it doesn't work.

What should I do to make this work on Lubuntu?

If this feature is not available in Lubuntu, what is alternative for this?

**Reference**
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/a11y-mag.html.en

**Update**

I've tested both `xzoom` and `KMag` and found `KMag` is better than `xzoom`. So I accepted that answer. If you know better apps, please let me know.

Comment: The feature in Ubuntu is part of the system and doesn't seem to be a separate application available to install in other desktop environments. So, Jim's answer mentioning *xzoom* is the easiest way to get some sort of magnification.

Comment: I've added information regarding installing kmag as a snap (available in 18.04+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have asked about your Zoom issue [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144249/can-some-programs-found-in-ubuntu-18-04-be-installed-in-other-desktop-environmen). My feeling is that some features of Ubuntu such as zoom and night light are integrated into gnome-shell and not available for installation in other desktop environments such as Lubuntu's.

While `xzoom` does address the basic issue of magnifying content (and is included in Ubuntu Mate), there is another program, kmag, which comes with more features. However, it should be noted that kmag is a qt-based application and so will pull in a lot of dependencies on Lubuntu 18.04. This should normally not be an issue with modern systems, but it is better to be aware. By the way, if you move up to the LXQt-based Lubuntu 18.10 or later, the additional dependencies will be minimal.

With

```
sudo apt install kmag
```

I see:

> 0 upgraded, 119 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need
>   to get 21.9 MB of archives. After this operation, 115 MB of additional
>   disk space will be used.

And with

```
sudo apt install --no-install-recommends kmag
```

I see

> 0 upgraded, 99 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded. Need
>   to get 18.2 MB of archives. After this operation, 98.7 MB of
>   additional disk space will be used.

What you see on your system in terms of dependencies *maybe* less if you already have other qt-based applications installed.

Here's an animated gif of some of the features kmag provides.

[image: kmag features]

---

**The snap route**
Kmag is available as a verified snap as well. Currently, the information provided by `snap info kmag` doesn't indicate the actual disk space used in case that is a matter of concern. See my question [How do I know what a snap will install?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1145345/248158) to know more.

Links:

- https://userbase.kde.org/KMag#Main_Features
- http://kmag.sourceforge.net/screenshots.html

Comment: Does kmag offer full screen magnifier?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192698/full-screen-magnifier-in-lubuntu-18

Comment: @Sabrina I don't think so. KDE Plasma has a full screen magnifier built into it.

Comment: @Sabrina https://youtu.be/a_JDhssrsMI?t=833 shows it in action for Kubuntu. Other than Ubuntu, I don't know of any other official Ubuntu flavor offering what you want.

Comment: @Sabrina if you don't mind, could you explain your need for magnification? I'm asking because several individual applications have their own zoom facility and using the application itself to zoom allows the user to type which isn't possible using the zoom provided by xzoom/kmag and the built-in accessibility zooms of Ubuntu/Kubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Not that I am aware of, there's none default screen magnifier app for Lubuntu.

But you can install it. `xzoom` able to magnify part of the screen.

```
sudo apt install xzoom
```

Navigate to **LXMenu → Universal Access → Screen Magnifier**

[image]

Drag your mouse cursor to area that you want to magnify. Below youtube videos explain it better.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Li45HK0YEQ0

Comment: Does xzoom offer full screen magnifier?

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1192698/full-screen-magnifier-in-lubuntu-18