# Can some programs found in Ubuntu 18.04 be installed in other desktop environments?

Tags: gnome, accessibility

Ubuntu 18.04 has programs such as Zoom (in Universal Access) and Night Light (in Displays). However, when I run Zoom, I see that *gnome-shell* is the responsible process in top.

[image: Running Zoom shows gnome-shell as the process]

And there aren't .desktop files in */usr/share/applications* corresponding to Zoom or Night Light.

Is it correct to assume that these programs are integral to gnome-shell the way Adwaita is built-in and are **not** available to be used in other desktop environments with `sudo apt install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR** - yes, these Zoom and Night Light are only for GNOME.

As far as I can see from `htop` and other clues as

```
# find Zoom
$ grep -r Zoom /usr/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop:Keywords=Keyboard;Mouse;a11y;Accessibility;Contrast;Zoom;Screen;Reader;text;font;size;AccessX;Sticky;Keys;Slow;Bounce;Mouse;Double;click;Delay;Assist;Repeat;Blink;
/usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop:Keywords=Shortcut;Workspace;Window;Resize;Zoom;Contrast;Input;Source;Lock;Volume;

# find Night
$ grep -r Night /usr/share/applications/
/usr/share/applications/gnome-display-panel.desktop:Keywords=Panel;Projector;xrandr;Screen;Resolution;Refresh;Monitor;Night;Light;Blue;redshift;color;sunset;sunrise;
```

Their `Exec` fields are the following:

```
# Zoom
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop | grep Exec
Exec=gnome-control-center universal-access

# Night
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-display-panel.desktop | grep Exec
Exec=gnome-control-center display

# Both
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop | grep Exec
Exec=gnome-control-center keyboard
```

They are shown only in:

```
# Zoom
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-universal-access-panel.desktop | grep Show
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;

# Night
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-display-panel.desktop | grep Show
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;

# Both
$ cat /usr/share/applications/gnome-keyboard-panel.desktop | grep Show
OnlyShowIn=GNOME;Unity;
```

above means only GNOME and Unity.

The top icon toggles GNOME specific configuation keys - for example Zoom toggles

```
/org/gnome/desktop/a11y/applications/screen-magnifier-enabled
```

between `true` and `false`. And this setting is expected to be applicable only to GNOME.

And Night Light toggles the GNOME-only configuration key:

```
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/color/night-light-enabled
```

---

So we can see that these *Zoom* and *Night Light* are related only to GNOME and Unity desktops.

Other desktop may have (or have not) alternatives for them. Night Light may be replaced with RedShift, accessibility tools are usually presented in desktops (for example MATE has `mate-at-properties`).