# How do I know what a snap will install?

Tags: snap, deb

OS: Ubuntu 18.04

When I search the software center for *kmag*, I get two results: one for a .deb and one for a snap.

The .deb mentions a download size of 627.5 kB:

[image: kmag .deb]

The snap download appears to be **smaller**, at 237.6 kB:

[image: kmag snap]

In the case of the .deb, because I have some knowledge, I can open a terminal and run `sudo apt install kmag` to find out that 6,744 kB of archives will actually be required taking up 36.4 MB of additional disk space.

How would a user, especially a relative newcomer, know **beforehand** what the snap installation will entail in terms of how much will be downloaded and how much additional disk space will be used?

---

I went through the process of installing the kmag snap on Ubuntu 19.04.

The following image shows the folder size of kde-frameworks-5-core18 is 865.6 MB whereas the folder size for kmag is only 679 kB. The information provided by the software center or by running `snap info kmag` doesn't give the user any clue that kde-frameworks-5-core18 will be installed (with a size of 865.6 MB).

[image: image of ncdu /snap]

Answer (score 0):

Get size information:
`snap info kmag`

Get more information about the snap format:
https://docs.snapcraft.io/snap-format

In short
A snap is a Squashfs file located in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/` mounted to `/snap/`

Comment: `snap info kmag` doesn't add much more information than what is seen in the software center.

Comment: I've provided more information based on an actual installation of the kmag snap.

Comment: thats why i dont like snaps and always prefer go with apt packages if availables