# How do I magnify a small area around around the pointer?

Tags: 18.04, gnome

I have looked at the default GNOME magnifier, and it either magnifies the whole screen, or half of it.  The full screen magnification means I can see only a quarter of the screen at once, and the half screen magnification stops following my pointer and jumps away when stop moving the mouse, making it useless.  Even if it did not do that it still hides too much of the screen.  I just sometimes need a little help seeing text when it's in a hard to read color or a bit too small, without affecting any of the screen beyond a small around around the pointer.

I have seen magnus, but it appears to put the magnified part of the screen in a totally different part of the screen, meaning I have to look away from where I'm trying to concentrate, as well as having to move the magnification window whenever I need to see what's actually under it - well, at least if I want to see it unmagnified.

I'm picturing something that looks like an actual (or really virtual) rectangular magnifying lens floating over the screen centered on the pointer.  Something like [this](http://magnifier.sourceforge.net/) except that that shows the mouse and lets you continue to work as if it's not there. How can I magnify the screen like this? Am I missing a knob to control the built-in GNOME magnifier? Is there a different magnifier I can use?

Comment: On xfce, holding alt and turning mouse wheel works!

Comment: @SeverusTux It looks like that zooms the entire desktop???

Comment: There's `kmag`. It's available as a snap (https://askubuntu.com/a/1144257/248158) or as a regular deb but the latter will pull in assorted KDE- or qt-dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `compiz`

```
sudo apt install compiz compiz-plugins compizconfig-settings-manager
```

Enable magnifier in CompizConfig Settings and adjust box size.

Press <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>m</kbd> to open magnifying box around the cursor.

[image]

Comment: how do i enable the magnifier once it's installed?

Comment: @Michael As shown in the gif above, go to CompizConfig settings manager and enable magnifier.

Comment: Sorry, the picture is a bit small to see - I don't see the CompizConfig settings manager... is that something separate to install?

Comment: @Michael, Oh sorry. No it is not something separate to install. After installing compiz, if you press `super` key and search for "Compiz", CompizComfig should appear. In that, you'll see an option to enable magnifier.

Comment: @Michael Or you can just launch it (Compiz settings manager) from the terminal with the command `ccsm`

Comment: oh hmm, that's weird. i did the search and found it, but when i clicked on it it brought up the ubuntu software center and i did have to install it

Comment: uh... when I run ccsm I don't see any many Accessibility options... only two options are listed and Magnifier is not one of them.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107749/discussion-between-severus-tux-and-michael).